# Какие проблемы вы видите в данном коде?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, товарищи программисты!
Какие проблемы вы видите в данном коде?

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(int j) { i=new int[j]; }
        ~Foo() { delete i; }
    private:
        int* i;
};

class Bar: Foo
{
    public:
        Bar(int j) { i=new char[j]; }
        ~Bar() { delete i; }
    private:
        char* i;
};

void main()
{
    Foo* f=new Foo(100);
    Foo* b=new Bar(200);
    *f=*b;
    delete f;
    delete b;
}
```

Comment: Отсутствие комментариев, описывающих идею этой программы.

Comment: @Asen Не надо удалять чужие комментарии без необходимости.

Comment: он написан на С++ =)

Comment: @Spectre, не надо переносить на других свои комплексы

Comment: А что не так с раскрытием того факта, что это тестовое задание для Яндекса?

Comment: Этот факт поначалу был раскрыт, а потом закрыт.

Comment: Вот мне и интересно, почему возникла такая шумиха вокруг этого и зачем это было прятать :-) Не вижу ничего особо постыдного в коллаборации с ними.

Comment: Я просто плохо знаю C++, видимо поэтому не понимаю, что будет происходить при new Bar(200) (в смысле конструктора Foo ведь он явно не вызывается из конструктора Bar). 

Отсюда и дальнейшее непонимание, что будет при обоих delete.

IMHO код путаный, для экспертов в C++.

Comment: А на самом деле хороший вопрос, правда провокационный. Проверка уровня отвечающих.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из того, что не сказано выше:

> Какие проблемы вы видите в данном коде?

Абсолютная бессмысленность кода. Классы, имеют бессмысленное название и ничего не делают, потому что у них нет никакого интерфейса. Bar имеет 2 члена с бессмысленным именем i, в которых можно запутаться и подумать, что это один указатель. Также нигде не хранится размер массива.

> Я пока заметил лишь утечку памяти в месте, где происходит копирование указателя...

Ты копируешь не указатели на объекты, а сами объекты. Это приводит к срезке, то есть копируется только половина объекта Bar, а именно указатель на int. При этом оба объекта начинают ссылаться на один и тот же кусок памяти, а память, выделенная объектом Foo утекает. При удалении f данные массива освобождаются, а b содержит висячий указатель в той части, которая унаследована от Foo. Второе освобождение этого блока памяти приводит к непредсказуемым последствиям.

Таким образом, код состоит из сплошных недостатков. Он абсолютно ничего не делает и его нельзя никак использовать. Хочешь статический массив - создавай на стеке, хочешь динамический - выделяй через new без посредников или используй контейнеры.

Comment: @GLmonster, вот Вы наверняка сможете объяснить.

При new Bar(200) какой базовый для него Foo будет создан ? В смысле, конструктор Foo будет вызван и если да, то с каким аргументом ?

Comment: Ну какой сумеет найти. Скорее всего -- не сможет ни какого (я пытался оттранслировать, g++ мне популярно объяснил: `error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo()’`

Comment: Кстати да, не обратил внимание. Конструктор Foo(int) не будет вызван. Конструктор базового класса с аргументами нужно вызывать явно в списке инициализации. Иначе вызывается конструктор без аргументов. Так как в классе Foo есть конструктор с аргументами, компилятор не генерирует конструктор по умолчанию. Поэтому будет ошибка компиляции.

Comment: **Вот !!! **

А я то думал, что совсем кресты не знаю. 

Код просто неправильный и нечего тут голову ломать об утечках и что случится в деструкторе и т.п.

Comment: Как в старом анекдоте:

       -- Ну как новая квартира? Недоделок много?
       -- Да пока одна?
       -- Это хорошо. Какая?
       -- Входная дверь не открывается.

Comment: Только в этом коде как раз недоделок полно. Входная дверь среди них.

Comment: Ну, так сразу и не скажешь, что ошибок полно...С первого взгляда, код выглядит вполне себе нормальным, рабочим.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно надо писать так:

```
int *i = new int[50];
delete[] i;
```

При такой записи в кучу возвращается не вcя память выделенная на массив:

```
int *i = new int[50];
delete i;
```

Eщё в этом коде объявляется указатель на класс который содержит единственный член, при чём сам этот член является указателем на массив целых чисел длина которого задается через конструктор. Одного этого уже достаточно чтобы отбить желание разбираться в таком С++ коде у нормального человека.

Comment: ну если обращать внимание на такие мелочи, то, да, это тоже баг. Спасибо. Но все же хотелось бы узнать о багах более серьёзных.

Comment: Это тоже не особо страшно, но проблематично. Забыть передать параметр конструктору вряд ли можно.=)

>Eщё в этом коде объявляется указатель на класс который содержит единственный член, при чём сам этот член является указателем на массив целых чисел длина которого задается через конструктор.

Comment: >При такой записи в кучу возвращается не вcя память выделенная на массив

Если я не ошибаюсь, единственное отличие между `delete[] arr` и `delete arr` заключается в том, что в первом случае будут вызваны деструкторы для всех элементов массива, а во втором -- только для первого. То есть для данного случая (встроенные типы) это лишь вопрос стиля.

Answer (score 1):

Нет вида наследования у класса Bar. Например, `class Bar: public Foo {...};`
В наследуемом классе имя переменной совпадает с переменной в базовом.

Comment: Ну эта глупость легко решаема: для этого достаточно в родительском классе сделать переменную **i** виртуальной.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы отметил одну большую проблему, которая упомянута у [@igumnov](/users/7053/igumnov), а именно выделение памяти в зависимости от параметра конструктора. Так запросто можно снести башку любому компу, достаточно на 64-х разрядной машинке вызвать:

```
Foo* f=new Foo(INT_MAX);
```

и все ляжет.

Я бы все таки ввел в код выделения памяти проверку на дуракоустойчивость - на минусы, на макс. размер массива и проч.

Comment: >Я бы все таки ввел в код выделения памяти проверку на дуракоустойчивость - на минусы, на макс. размер массива и проч.

 Так обычно следует делать с кодом, который может быть полезен. Для проверки на дуракоустойчивость надо просто удалить весь код выше, оставив пустой main.

Answer (score 1):

Название переменных мне ни о чем не говорит. Прочитайте 11 главу(Сила имен переменных) из книги "Совершенный код"

Comment: Абсолютно согласен.

Comment: Как раз к именам притензий нет. 

@Антон Феоктистов, не надо придумывать "осмысленные" имена к коду, который проверяет уровень отвечающего. А то они запутают его (отвечающего) еще больше.

Comment: Вы с точки зрения вообще не надо, или только конкретно данного окода?

Comment: Это тестовое задание, не имеющее никакого отношения к реальной работе, поэтому замечание совсем не к месту.

Answer (score 0):

**Итак, какие же на самом деле в этом коде существуют ошибки:**

Ну можно начать с того, что код вообще не запустится на стадии компиляции! Главная функция (main) ничего не возвращает( `void main()` ), а должна возвращать "int" =>( `int main()` ).

**Второе:**

Ошибка в конструкторе Bar.

Для посторения объекта должен быть вызван конструктор базового класса. Т.к специально не указано, какой конструктор надо вызвать, то компилятор пытается подставить вызов конструктора по умолчанию `"Foo::Foo()"`, но такой не определен в классе `"Foo"`

**Третье**

В конструкторах обоих классов нет проверки на отрицателность переменной `"j"`, вследствие чего конструктор будет пытаться создать массив с отрицательной размерностью, а это беда...

**Четвертое( утечки памяти ):**

В данном коде есть целых две(!) утечки памяти! Первая очевидна, происходит копирование указателя. А вот вторая утечка скрыта в вызове `"delete b"`. Данный вызов удалит объект `*b`, но вызовет деструктор только Foo-части объекта `*b`, т.к деструктор не виртуален.
Результат: повторное освобождения памяти `*b`

**Вывод:**  сплошная дырка, а не код...ошибка почти в каждой строке.

```
Тестировалось в компиляторе gcc 4.6  .
```

Comment: Последняя версия - это какая? Можно уточнить?

Comment: Не, не последняя, как оказалось( думал последняя ) 4.6

Comment: >В данном коде есть целых две(!) утечки памяти! Первая очевидна, происходит копирование указателя.

 Происходит копирование ОБЪЕКТОВ, а с ними и указателей внутри них.

>Главная функция (main) ничего не возвращает( void main() ), а должна возвращать "int"

 В некоторых компиляторах так можно писать. Например, в Visual C++.